# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \ln\big(P\big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\geq a\big)\big)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limits, random-variables

I try to solve the following task, but I have no idea. Do you have a small hint?
Let $X_n$ be some iid sequence of random variables with $P(X_1=0)=P(X_1=1)=0.5$. Let $a\in (\frac{1}{2},1)$. Determine
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \ln\big(P\big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\geq a\big)\big)$

Answer (score 4):

Let $S_n= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_i$. By Law of Large Numbers $\frac {S_n} n \to \frac 1  2$ (and so $S_n \to \infty$)(a.s.); so $P(S_n \geq a) \to 1$ Hence, the limit is $0$.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning, but there is a $1/n$ in front of the logarithm. Unless I'm mistaken, this makes a difference.

Comment: It's shown that the log part is bounded (i.e doesn't tend to $-\infty$) so the product converges to zero. @Idontgetit

Comment: If $x_n \to 0$ then $\frac 1 n x_n \to $ even faster! @Idontgetit

Comment: Got it, thanks! My post was erroneous (I took the cdf instead of the tail probability), so I removed it.

Comment: Surely, $\lim_{\frac{1}{n}}\log \Pr(S_n>na)$ is more interesting!